# Showing content when RecyclerView is empty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am trying to show some text when RecyclerView is empty by setting the text

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

and making its

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

when RecyclerView is empty, but I am trying to apply that when someone deletes the last item of the RecyclerView.

In another words, I want to show the text when last item of the RecyclerView is deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question, but usually empty Views get text from `android:text` or even from `android:hint`. I just don't know if that's possible after the View content is deleted. What are you getting after you delete an item?

Comment: check if the list is empty show the text that indicates the empty ...if not hide that text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for delete:

```
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);
```

And now the callback,

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.UP) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "on Move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "on Swiped ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Remove swiped item from list and notify the RecyclerView
            final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
 };
```

You can now identify which of your item has been swiped. You can delete the item from your adapter and can `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void manageEmptyView() { if (perticularFragmentsAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) { rv_perticularfragment_listing.setVisibility(View.GONE); txt_ParticualrFragment_emptyVIew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } }
```

Copy above method in your activity and call this method on the delete event from your adapter by using passing your activity as a context.

Comment: Good but the question is tagged as kotlin.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
if (mAdapter.getItemCount() === 0)
{
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

Comment: I already wrote this code and it works only when the app closed or opened , I used it with onResume and it works. Now I want to run this code when the last item deleted from the recyclerview

Comment: I do not know how you implement a deletion, but I would simply call this from there or create an interface and callback from somewhere else.

Comment: on your deletion login success add this 

`if(mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0){
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }`